# IntelliJ Build Error Context Mismatch

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I want to use IntelliJ IDEA 15 instead of Android Studio, but I have a problem with building. I get the following error:

```
Gradle sync failed: The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch: 
Java home is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Tim\.gradle\daemon,pid=1224,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=DE,-Duser.language=de,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=6fd89265-5686-4337-a75f-538209464d3a,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Tim\.gradle\daemon,pid=14128,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=DE,-Duser.language=de,-Duser.variant]
```

What is my mistake? As you can see on the following pictures everything is configured correctly.

I have configured a JDK and the Android Tools as follows:

[image: Project]
[image: SDK2]
[image: SDK1]

Comment: Something is pointing to IntelliJ's build in Jre (`C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0\jre`) maybe find if that is a setting anywhere

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I found this question while investigating a similar problem, and I solved mine, so maybe my experience will help.

### Observations

My problem was similar to yours in that the `Wanted` context had the `javaHome` as the path to the JRE embedded in the IDEA install folder, and the `Actual` context had it as the first version of Java on my path.  I found several similar error reports online but none had the IDEA embedded JRE as the `Wanted` version.

The `Wanted` Java version happened to be a system-wide install of the JRE, and not the JDK I had configured for the project, nor the value set for `JAVA_HOME`, which made me very suspicious (and confused).  Re-ordering my path caused it to use yet another "unwanted" version of Java, so it was clearly using the path to choose what to run, but it wasn't clear why.  I couldn't make IntelliJ's embedded JRE be first on my path, because I needed that to be the JDK for various reasons, so I needed another solution.

I also noticed (using Process Explorer, since I'm on Windows) that, in the failing case, IntelliJ launched a number of `java.exe` Gradle daemon processes, and that there were definitely no daemon processes running before I tried to start my build.

### Solution

The cause turned out to be that I had defined a new configuration in the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog and put the full path to the `build.gradle` file in the `Gradle project:` field, as follows.  (I did this by clicking the ellipsis (...) button to the right of the field, but I could also have entered it directly.)

[image: Run/Debug Configurations dialog showing Gradle project as an explicit path to a Gradle build file]

However, what I should have done was follow the pattern in existing configurations, where the `Gradle project:` was specified as a "registered project", by clicking the "folder" icon to the right of the field, highlighted in green in the following image.  In this case, the content of the field is just the project name, and is shown with subtly different background/foreground colours.  (I accidentally discovered that right-clicking on this name will replace it with the path to the folder containing `build.gradle`, but if you cancel and start editing the configuration again, it will still appear as just the project name.)

[image: Run/Debug Configurations dialog showing Gradle project as the name of a registered project]

After making this change, the configuration built as expected, and I observed that only one `java.exe` was launched, using the same JDK path as when I ran tasks from the "Gradle" panel in the UI.

Comment: Not in a million years would I have figured this out. That was exactly it. Thank you!

Comment: I only figured this out because there were several very similar pre-existing configurations in the project which _did_ work, so I could spot the difference in the ".xml" file and then poke around the UI until I worked out how to fix it there.

Comment: I tried this and was still getting the error.  I changed my shortcut to use the idea64.exe instead of the 32 bit launcher and it did solve it as Percy Vega suggested.

Comment: I had the same error and it turned out that I was running a gradle task that was defined in a particular project, but I hadn't specified that project in the Run Configuration.

Comment: Man you saved me at least a few hours... there's no way I can figure this out. This exactly fixed my problem.

Comment: For me, Gradle got confused about module settings after changes to the `build.gradle` files.

I removed all the Gradle modules (under Project Structure -> Modules) and re-added them as imported Gradle modules.

Comment: You da real mvp

Answer (score 42):

I solved it by using idea64.exe and not idea.exe

[image]

Answer (score 29):

1. Create file `gradle.properties` in folder `%USERPROFILE%\.gradle\` (`~/.gradle/` on *nix machines)
2. In this file add string `org.gradle.java.home={actual path to jdk}` (to know it in MacOS run `/usr/libexec/java_home`)

Comment: Tried the other solutions, this is the only one to work for me. The problem occurred for me when I upgraded to Intellij 2016.3.1 and opted for the 64 bit JRE. I could not get Gradle to NOT want that JRE after that.

Answer (score 14):

For me this issue was solved by running IDE in 64 bit mode since I only have 64 bit JRE installed.

Comment: Thanks! I had this same issue and ensuring that I ran the 64 bit version of IntelliJ solved the issue!

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem and this is what worked for me.

I deleted the `.idea` and `.project` files from the root directory of my IntelliJ **project**. Restarted IntelliJ and opened my project again.

Comment: After trying tens of possible solutions, this one magically worked for me. I've faced this problem after upgrade Intellij from 2016.2 to .3, (and gradle 2.10 to 2.14).

Comment: EDIT: Unfortunately does not fix it. After deleting ".idea" the project rebuild gradle (downloads and configures), after that everything runs smoothly but after relaunch of the IDE. The problem came back again.

Comment: I just found myself experiencing this for the same reason Xarvalus seems to be. It was fine the first time I used it, then I ran the 64bit IDEA version just to have a look-see, and now apparently cannot go back to the 32 bit. It seems to be fine if I continue with the 64 bit IDEA.

Comment: I was mistaken. Seems there are old settings lying around in .gradle. Getting rid of that seems to make it happy.

Comment: I went into a weird state with Intellij and deleted my .idea project. Unfortunately, this is what broke gradle for me. Multiple retries and trying to address things in different ways didn't help. The last thing that helped is deleting both the `.gradle` and `.idea` projects. All of sudden, everything worked magically!

Answer (score 6):

For MacOSX, what solved the problem for me was to point the SDK in IntelliJ to `Contents/Home`. For example:

This:

> /Users//.sdkman/candidates/java/14.0.1-zulu/zulu-14.jdk/Contents/Home

instead of this:

> /Users//.sdkman/candidates/java/14.0.1-zulu

It is working with the latest, at this time, Java (14.0.1-zulu), Gradle (6.5) and Kotlin (1.4-M2).

Comment: Thank you! After trying a number of things, this finally fixed my issue.

Comment: This worked with zulu 1.8.0_272 on osx big sur, intellij 2020.2

Comment: Tactical comment to help me find this specific answer again when I inevitably hit the problem again when installing a new JDK

Comment: @MichalM, that's funny and nice ;)

Answer (score 3):

Add below in your gradle.propetries

org.gradle.java.home=${sdk_path}

for example:

org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

Otherwise if you have memory heap warning.

Please also add gradle.properties with below:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m

Comment: This solved it for me.  I set org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home in my project's gradle.properties and the problem went away.  Note that I had already correctly configured my run configuration as HughG had suggested, but this step was also necessary for me.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

- uninstalling intelliJ
- Re-install intelliJ, but during the installation make sure you **DON'T** check "Download and install 64-bit JRE by JetBrains (will be used with the 64-bit launcher)"

This made my project work again, (in both he 32 and 64 bit version).

Comment: Did you need to delete the caches and settings when you uninstalled it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I kept my settings (I don't remember having to redo my hotkeys).  And I probably had already deleted the cache trying to get it to work before this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using `11.0.8-amzn` instead of `11.0.8-zulu`.

Cost me two hours of my life to get the builds working again in the IDE

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only went to settings, searched for JDK, clicked Java Compiler, then I noticed the project bytecode version was missing. So I only checked 1.8 which is my Java build version.  And that was it for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just move the jdk folder to intellij wanted folder C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3.4\jre

then change the values in .gradle folder given in wanted line close the project then restart

it works for me....

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by renaming jre and jre64 folders to prevent idea from using them and setting JAVA_HOME to my other JDK 1.8 installation in the idea.bat file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Gradle IDEA plugin:

1. Run `.\gradlew cleanidea idea`
2. Quit IntelliJ IDEA
3. Start IntelliJ IDEA and choose the "Import Project" option from the main menu.
4. Navigate to your project's main `build.gradle` file when asked to specify the project to import.
5. You'll then get the chance to set the JDK to "the project default" or another preferred JDK.
6. Click OK to continue, and watch Gradle sync and build again successfully!

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem got solved when I switched from `11.0.14-zulu` to another vendor of java 11.