# Intellij idea says Java Home is Different

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch:
Java home is different.

```
Wanted:DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=/home/administrator/Downloads/idea-IU-145.1617.8/jre,daemonRegistryDir=/home/administrator/.gradle/daemon,pid=11963,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IN,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
```

Actual:

```
DefaultDaemonContext[uid=4839fb8c-418b-4666-9a66-40a60133958a,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/home/administrator/.gradle/daemon,pid=15202,idleTimeout=60000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IN,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ Build Error Context Missmatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536013/intellij-build-error-context-missmatch)

Comment: Please ask an actual question or at least describe the problem rather than only quoting an error message. (The error message may of course be part of a question, but it shouldn't be the only part.)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Though I did not find the root cause where the different javaHomes have been taken from, at least I found a workaround that worked for me:

Try setting the following in your `gradle.properties` (either in `$HOME/.gradle/` or in your project build dir):

```
org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me on OS X.  I used org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home -- thanks.

Comment: Yes I set `org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home` in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` (which did not previously exist on my Mac)

Comment: create a file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties and put `org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home` as contents. Make sure use your own JAVA_HOME.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.1 (Community Edition), I can not make it run using Java 11 (Azul), switching to Java 8 (Azul) based on Project SDK on Gradle settings, works.

Answer (score 69):

Be sure to check and correct JDK version in these 3 places:

1. Check `Preferences -> Build,... -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JVM`:
   [image: Gradle Preferences]
2. Check `Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Project -> Project SDK`:
   [image: Project]
3. Check `Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs`:
   [image: SDKs]

Fixing gradle.properties is a dirty workaround. Better fix this at the IDE level.

Comment: I checked all of these and they were correct but it still is giving me the same error

Comment: Worked for me! In my case it appears that i've installed several times the same JDK version with sdkman. Checking that the same config appear in this 3 places really works!

Comment: I disagree. Fixing this in `gradle.properties` is a purposeful fix. It has the advantage that it also works when executing Gradle from the CLI or from other applications. Instead the environment-specific configuration of your IDE should be kept to a minimum. Still I would recommend to configure it in your user specific properties file and not pollute the project's one with your personal settings.

Comment: For me, I was using java 11 in the IDEA GUI, but I had java 1.8 specified in the gradle.properties.  Changing from 11 to 8 in the GUI fixed the error.

Answer (score 3):

Worked like magic.. have been struggling for 2 days now, just add:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home
```

in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file.

Comment: To restate this for Windows., ~\.gradle\gradle.properties
  org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_192/jre

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ broke when I copied `tools.jar` to a `jre/lib`, attempting to make hot attach work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41053289/4427938) helped me.

**Solution**: In the bin folder of IntelliJ where you have it installed, run `idea64.exe` not `idea.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Fwiw - Had a similar thing after, and just reopening the project by picking the build.gradle file fixed it.  (Also, done `brew cask install java` which placed jdk 10 in the default path)

Answer (score 1):

For me this is solved when I selected the `Project SDK` option in gradle JVM. Even it was same when selected manually.

[the preference window in intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtebr.png)

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned methods did not work for me. I am using Big Sur 11.4, M1 mac.

Remove Java like in the link below and reinstall it:
https://actonnotes.wordpress.com/2020/11/22/how-to-remove-openjdk-version-15-on-apple-macos/

Answer (score 0):

I struggled it whole day. For my case, it's not related to intellij. But as the repo uses an very outdated version of gradlew of 4.9. And it always complain a about a particular `pid` in the same error message. Which when I using `jps` or `ps`, it wasn't there. That drives me crazy. I reboot my machine many times, it still complains about the same pid. Later I found it cached the pid in the folder of: `~/.gradle/daemon/...`. Such a dumb error message and logic. The finally I solved this problem but cleanup the whole `~/.gradle` folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
Java home is different.
Expecting: '/Users/******/.sdkman/candidates/java/current' but was: '/Users/*****/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.16.1-zulu/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home'.


Please configure the JDK to match the expected one.
```

for me me none of any of those suggestion worked. I am using mac with sdk man to manage the jdks. I checked gradle wrapper version in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`  and updated from `6.8.2` to  `6.9.3` and it worked.