# Gradle — The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, java, nixos, nixpkgs

I installed the OpenJDK via [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) in Ubuntu (`Linux uplink 4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 10:13:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`).

```
gorre@uplink:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_172"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b02, mixed mode)

gorre@uplink:~$ which java
/home/gorre/.nix-profile/bin/java

gorre@uplink:/nix/store/f9053w1lfrkhgqfpr6l82ssxmjpsni1j-openjdk-8u172b02$ ll
total 24K
dr-xr-xr-x 3 gorre 4.0K Dec 31  1969 share/
dr-xr-xr-x 2 gorre 4.0K Dec 31  1969 nix-support/
dr-xr-xr-x 3 gorre 4.0K Dec 31  1969 lib/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 gorre   80 Dec 31  1969 jre -> /nix/store/n7rh8v269qb1fs6314yq0wg7q8cajw0g-openjdk-8u172b02-jre/lib/openjdk/jre/
dr-xr-xr-x 2 gorre 4.0K Dec 31  1969 include/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 gorre   76 Dec 31  1969 bin -> /nix/store/f9053w1lfrkhgqfpr6l82ssxmjpsni1j-openjdk-8u172b02/lib/openjdk/bin/
```

Now when I try build/run a project that uses `Gradle 4.4` within `IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-173.4548.28` I get this error:

```
The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch: 
Java home is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=/nix/store/f9053w1lfrkhgqfpr6l82ssxmjpsni1j-openjdk-8u172b02,daemonRegistryDir=/home/gorre/.gradle/daemon,pid=12824,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=b813ba02-e4a6-4bfe-91b2-8ed32963f7cc,javaHome=/nix/store/f9053w1lfrkhgqfpr6l82ssxmjpsni1j-openjdk-8u172b02/lib/openjdk,daemonRegistryDir=/home/gorre/.gradle/daemon,pid=14245,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
```

I've searched here and there but the other answers/solutions don't work, not even specifying the Java home in `gradle.properties` (inside the project or in my user's home):

```
org.gradle.java.home = /nix/store/f9053w1lfrkhgqfpr6l82ssxmjpsni1j-openjdk-8u172b02
```

On the other hand, if I build/run the project on a terminal it works fine. Any clues?

---

**UPDATE #1**

This is my configuration for Gradle and the SDK in IntelliJ IDEA:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have specified the `org.gradle.java.home` property in gradle.properties file file that is located in the same directory as build.gradle or in UDER_HOME/.gradle directory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38212434/2000323 Try restarting the PC. Also check what is JAVA_HOME environment validate is set to. Try to set it to the JDK you are using for Gradle and remove `org.gradle.java.home` property re-login might be needed for changes to take effect). Issue also may be caused by symlink. Try removing the one for `jre` subdirectory.

Comment: @Andrey I tried the `org.gradle.java.home` "trick" inside `gradle.properties` — it's in the question itself. On the other hand, (a) I did restart, (b) I don't have `JAVA_HOME` declared and/or set as environment variable, and (c) deleted the link for the `jre`...but nothing happens, still the same error.

Comment: Did you @x80486 ever came to a solution? I've got the same. But my project was working for some time, but then something happened and now I can't use it anymore.

Comment: @jmizv, in my case it was what I answered below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out, even though it was in front of my nose — I didn't read carefully the error message(s).

Basically, the `default` Java home set by Nix was at: `/nix/store/f9053w1lfrkhgqfpr6l82ssxmjpsni1j-openjdk-8u172b02/lib/openjdk` and the one I manually set inside IntelliJ IDEA was at: `/nix/store/f9053w1lfrkhgqfpr6l82ssxmjpsni1j-openjdk-8u172b02` (notice the missing `../lib/openjdk` segment).

After correcting that in IntelliJ IDEA everything worked fine. I didn't need anything additional and/or special.

I hope this helps someone else in the future — or any other fast-reader [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/)'ers.

Answer (score 6):

Check Idea settings for Gradle daemon:

```
Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle.
```

There is an option "Gradle JVM". Looks that Idea uses Java 9 or some other non-compatible JVM to run Gradle.
Yoy should select your Java version from Nix.

Comment: Yeah, I've checked that also. I'm actually using the right one there. I'll update the answer with two screen-shots for this one.