# How to solve “ Gradle sync failed: The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected?”

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

I’ve tried all the suggestions at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536013/intellij-build-error-context-mismatch#) including setting the gradle.properties  JAVA_HOME to actual path… but non worked for me. Please help.

Some details:
System: windows 32bit

Environment variable Path:  C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\HI-TECH Software\PICC\lite\9.60\bin;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;D:\Softwares\bin

IDE: Android Studio 3.0

JDK, JRE  version(the one in C:\program files\java…) : jdk1.8.0_111, jre1.8.0_121 respectively

Full Error message:  Gradle sync failed: The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected. It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch:  Java home is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=D:\Android sudio\android-studio\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\User.gradle\daemon,pid=6568,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=cb87848b-f0d9-4feb-abfb-b6562a0e6618,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\User.gradle\daemon,pid=5448,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]

Comment: Did you try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40888051/104891?

Comment: yes, i first tried with single slashes but it wasn't recognized as directory. i read somewhere to use double slashes and it recognized it as directory but the Error persisted. org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program files\\Java

Comment: That is not a correct java home directory, you have to specify the subdirectory with the exact version.

Comment: It might be easier for you to install via package manager - https://gradle.org/install/

Comment: Oh sorry i meant org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111