# Gradle Project Issue In Intellij

Tags: java, gradle

I have one Gradle Project that I have imported into Intellij 2018, after importing it show

**Sync up Error:**

```
The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
Java home is different.
Expecting: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66' but was: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre'.
Please configure the JDK to match the expected one.
```

I cross checked all the places where it picked up the path:

- Check environment variable in my computer, it is fine and only single entire is there.
- Check path command on cmd it show the same single path.
- Check on Intellij it also set Same Java Home path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ Build Error Context Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536013/intellij-build-error-context-mismatch)

Comment: I saw your shared Link and try all combination shared inside that link but it didn't work for me it shows the same error.